# Google calendar event response notifications to non-google email addresses no longer sent

Tags: email, gmail, google-calendar-api, icalendar

Up until approximately 1 month ago, we were able to achieve full calendar sync using event response email notifications from google calendar:

1. our system generated an email with an ics attachment
2. the user responded via gmail or google calendar
3. the email address listed for the organizer in the ics file received an event response email notification with corresponding ics information
4. our system ingested the ics file to keep their response in sync

We have now noticed that **event response email notifications are no longer sent to non-gmail organizer email addresses**.

We were able to confirm the change in behavior using yahoo calendar/mail as well:

**Notifications Sent:**

- create google calendar event, invite user via a gmail address, invitee responds via google calendar/gmail
- create google calendar event, invite yahoo email address, invitee responds via yahoo calendar/yahoo mail

**Notifications Not Sent:**

- create yahoo calendar event, invite gmail address, invitee responds via google calendar/gmail

Anybody have experience with this? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout these few resources:

- [google calendar invites are sometimes marked as spam](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/UCwcp_Gcjos)

  - solution: add email filter to never mark emails from `calendar-notification@google.com` as spam.
- [google calendar help - invitation not received](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/46895?hl=en&ref_topic=1672537)

  - solution 1: same thing, check spam folder.
  - solution 2: check calendar notification settings.
- [yahoo calenda help - not getting reminders](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN3854.html)

  - solution: check spam filters.

It may also help to add the address to your contacts so that it will be less likely that the notifications are marked as spam.

Comment: Appreciate the attempt, but none of this is relevant to the issue.